# How to take screenshots in Borderlands 2 without third-party software?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is there a way to take a screenshot in Borderlands 2 with a certain shortcut (so i don't have to use third-party software) ?

Comment: ...Print Screen doesn't work?

Comment: @fbueckert I wonder if windows technically counts as 3rd party software?

Comment: @fbueckert Print Screen does not work.

Comment: Print Screen works for me in Windows 8 (I assume 7 too) with Full Screen Windowed mode.

Comment: Print Screen works for me on Windows 7

Comment: I'm using Windows XP and Print Screen doesn't work on it for Borderlands 2 =/

Comment: Is there not a setting inside Borderlands 2 to set a hot key for a print screen? I'd assume they would have one.

Comment: @leety Nope there is none.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? If all you get after a Print Screen screenshot is a large black square, have you tried running the game in windowed mode rather than full screen?

Comment: @TrentHawkins Nope because i highly dislike playing in windowed. Anyway now it's too late to try it out anyway as i unistalled Borderlands 2 (i loved the game a lot but the game got buged in one map and it would crash there all the time so i couldn't continue)

Comment: @ChrisHateZ I'm with you as far as playing in windowed mode goes - but I've encountered this problem in a different game. At some point (don't know if it was after a graphics driver update, Direct X update, or what) I stopped being able to take screenshots in City of Heroes, all I got was a black box as big as the game's resolution. But if I temporarily switched to windowed mode it worked just fine. It's not ideal for taking screenshots on-the-fly, but if you really want to screenshot an awesome item or character screen, it worked for City of Heroes. Something to keep in mind for future needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm aware of no in-game, purely first-party mechanism for taking a screenshot.

However (as Kexlox discovered), Borderlands 2 on PC is currently Steam-exclusive. Steam offers screenshot capabilities, in-game by way of the 'P' button when looking at significant items (weapons, shields, grenade mods), and otherwise by way of the 'F12' button.

Comment: There are, of course, numerous third-party solutions to the screenshot problem, if you're on PC. Steam, for one.

Comment: I'm not sure if steam is really third-party for borderlands 2, that's sort of debatable, but it does screenshots quite well.

Comment: Considering Borderlands 2 is not Steam-exclusive on the PC platform, I'd say it definitely counts as third-party.

Comment: I know about the taking screenshots of items while using the "Inspect" option,my question is about taking screenshots in general.

Comment: Erm,i just went to check screenshots i made using "P" in inspect mode and i noticed i don't have any,can you try taking screenshot with "P" shortcut and let me know did it actually take a screenie?

Comment: Borderlands 2 is steam exclusive on PC.  It's a steamworks DRM'ed game, no matter where you buy it, it installs into steam.  Checking inspect screenshots now.

Comment: In fact, taking a screenshot in inspect mode, with "P" took a steam screenshot.  When I left game the steam screenshot manager came up and asked if I wanted to save it in the cloud or locally.

Comment: @Kex: Oh, didn't know that. Weird.

In light of your findings, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 and below:

### <kbd>Print SCR</kbd>

---

Windows 8 and up:

```
SUPER+Print SCR
```

It should be in `YOURDIR\Pictures\Screenshots`

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't solved this problem, you can go to System Preferences, then select Keyboard, then access Keyboard Shortcuts. Press on the Mission Control tab on the right of the window, and uncheck "Show Dashboard"